# How to download JRE 1.8 for production environment?

Tags: java, oracle, java-8

I'd like to use some Java8 features in my program. But I should deliver the program within 10 days and seeing that JRE 8 isn't available by oracle worries me. I see that Java8 features have been estabilished and looks to be very stable. My project is in the production camp and not for experiment.

When I search java runtime environment 8 or 1.8 I find nothing published by oracle. Am I making a mistake or I will have to install JDK8 for the client(The worst option). Or I should rewrite all the Java8 codes and make the software compatible with Java7.?

Is there another vendor who has the Java8 ready and if there is, is it wise to use their JRE in spite of the oracle one? Will it remain compatible?

Comment: No, Java 8 is expected to be release around March 2014, you shouldn't be depending on that features early, so you won't get link on Oracle website.

Comment: And remember that, like every time before when a new version was released, there were lots of bugs and you got a new update every few days. I wouldn't ever recommend Java 1.8 in any kind of production environment before autumn 2014.

Comment: I would highly recommend against using pre-release / beta software in a production environment ... but that's just me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java 8 is not yet officially released, not from Oracle or any other vendor. There exists pre-release versions, but for a fully supported solution you have to wait until next year. You shouldn't depend on java 8 features yet for production quality code.

## Update

Java 8 was fully released on 18 March 2014. It can be downloaded [here (jre)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html) or [here (jdk)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

Comment: please update your answer